# When using Keyboard Shortcut : Command is being invoked from C:\Windows\system32 instead of Current Directory

Tags: windows, cmd, shortcut

My target is to create a folder named `_Misc` in the current folder using shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+M`

I created a shortcut in desktop.

In the properties of the shortcut, went to the `Shortcut` tab and put the following values

- Target: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k mkdir _Misc`
- Start in: `%CD%`
- Shortcut Key: `Ctrl+Alt+M`

[image]

Now, when I press `Ctrl+Alt+M` in any folder, for example: `D:\Test` it says

```
Access is denied.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

So I think the the command `mkdir _Misc` is being invoked from `C:\Windows\system32` instead of `D:\Test`

What do I need to do?

Comment: maybe mkdir D:\Test\_Misc?

Comment: I am willing to use this shortcut in different directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach can never work. The shortcut key of a shortcut file can be used anywhere. For example Windows executes the `Target` command line even when <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+M</kbd> is pressed while viewing this page in browser. Which directory should be the current directory on browser having input focus?

A solution is using the **Send to** context menu which is customizable by adding shortcuts to folder `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` on Windows Vista / Server 2008 or any later Windows version. The directory is `%UserProfile%\SendTo` on Windows XP / Server 2003.

Create a batch file in a directory you want with following lines:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" exit
if not exist "%~1" exit

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Directory=%~1"
if "%Directory:~-1%" == "\" goto MakeDirectory
if not exist "%~1\" for %%I in ("%~1") do set "Directory=%%~dpI" & goto MakeDirectory
set "Directory=%Directory%\"

:MakeDirectory
if not exist "%Directory%_Misc\" md "%Directory%_Misc"
endlocal & if exist "%Directory%_Misc\" cd /D "%Directory%_Misc"
```

Line two and three result in exiting batch file and started command process if the batch file is called without any argument or with a string which is not an existing directory or file.

The next lines make it possible to **Send to** a full qualified directory or file name to the batch file. Directory or file names with relative paths are not really supported by this batch file.

Windows Explorer passes a full qualified directory name without a backslash at end to the batch file. But in case of argument one is a string ending with a backslash, the batch file knows at this execution step that first argument references a directory which really exists and so can immediately continue with creating the subdirectory.

The argument can reference an existing directory or an existing file in case of string of argument one is not ending with a backslash as on being invoked from Windows Explorer context menu **Send to**. For that reason the batch file next checks if the argument string references a file in which case it uses the file path as directory path.

Then the subdirectory `_Misc` is created if that directory does not already exist. This works even with a UNC path starting with `\\ServerName\ShareName\` passed to the batch file.

Last the temporary environment is deleted using `endlocal` resulting in deletion of environment variable `Directory` and restoring initial current directory as it was pushed on stack on execution of command `setlocal`. For that reason the last command line contains two commands: `endlocal` to restore default environment and an `if` for checking existence of subdirectory `_Misc` and making this directory the current directory after execution of `endlocal`.

Please note that `cd /D` fails by default if a UNC path was passed to the batch file.

This batch file must be called from a shortcut file created in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` on Windows Vista and later versions of Windows with a name you like to see in **Send to** context menu and with an icon you prefer for this context menu item.

The `Target` in shortcut properties must be:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /K "Path to batch file\BatchFileName.bat"
```

Shortcut property `Start in` can be empty in which case `%USERPROFILE%` is used by Windows Explorer, or there is an existing directory specified which is used as default current directory in case of last line fails because of subdirectory `_Misc` could not be created because of missing required permissions.

The started command process **keeps** running because of option `/K` after finishing execution of the batch file. The command process would be closed on using option `/C` instead of `/K`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1`
- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`